Donkeycar: donkey ui command raise RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded') problem
I'm following this guide:
https://docs.donkeycar.com/guide/host_pc/setup_ubuntu/
since I have to install donkey ui on my laptop to train a deep learning autopilot.
The problem arise when I try to launch the donkey ui command.
My configuration is the following:
donkeycar==5.1.0
tensorflow==2.15.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.37.1
cuda==12.3
CuDNN =8.9
I got the following problem:
   using donkey v5.1.0 ...
   INFO:kivy:Kivy: v2.3.0
   INFO:kivy:Logger: Record log in /home/wre/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-08-30_9.txt
   [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/wre/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-08-30_9.txt
   [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
INFO:kivy:Kivy: Installed at "/home/wre/Scrivania/donkey/minoconda3/envs/donkey/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/wre/Scrivania/donkey/minoconda3/envs/donkey/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
INFO:kivy:Python: v3.11.9 (main, Apr 19 2024, 16:48:06) [GCC 11.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.9 (main, Apr 19 2024, 16:48:06) [GCC 11.2.0]
INFO:kivy:Python: Interpreter at "/home/wre/Scrivania/donkey/minoconda3/envs/donkey/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/wre/Scrivania/donkey/minoconda3/envs/donkey/bin/python"
INFO:kivy:Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
INFO:kivy:Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
INFO:kivy:Factory: 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
INFO:kivy:Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
INFO:kivy:Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
INFO:kivy:Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
INFO:kivy:GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
INFO:kivy:GL: Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
INFO:kivy:GL: OpenGL version <b'4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.3-1pop1~1711635559~22.04~7a9f319'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.3-1pop1~1711635559~22.04~7a9f319'>
INFO:kivy:GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
INFO:kivy:GL: OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)'>
INFO:kivy:GL: OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
INFO:kivy:GL: Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
INFO:kivy:GL: Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
INFO:kivy:GL: Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
INFO:kivy:Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
INFO:kivy:Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
2024-08-30 14:24:41.294841: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-08-30 14:24:41.294865: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-08-30 14:24:41.295527: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-08-30 14:24:41.299280: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering Relayout (<function _relayout_gradient at 0x7849b9b0d080>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering Relayout (<function _relayout_gradient at 0x7849b9b0d080>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering RelayoutLike (<function _relayout_grad_gradient at 0x7849b9b0d1c0>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering RelayoutLike (<function _relayout_grad_gradient at 0x7849b9b0d1c0>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering CopyToMesh (<function _copy_to_mesh_gradient at 0x7849b9b0dc60>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering CopyToMesh (<function _copy_to_mesh_gradient at 0x7849b9b0dc60>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering CopyToMeshGrad (<function _copy_to_mesh_grad_gradient at 0x7849b9b0dbc0>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering CopyToMeshGrad (<function _copy_to_mesh_grad_gradient at 0x7849b9b0dbc0>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxArgs (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxArgsGradient at 0x7849b91d6200>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxArgs (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxArgsGradient at 0x7849b91d6200>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsGradient at 0x7849b91d63e0>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsGradient at 0x7849b91d63e0>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsPerChannel (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsPerChannelGradient at 0x7849b91d6b60>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsPerChannel (<function _FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsPerChannelGradient at 0x7849b91d6b60>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering QuantizeAndDequantizeV4 (<function _QuantizeAndDequantizeV4Grad at 0x7849b91d6c00>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering QuantizeAndDequantizeV4 (<function _QuantizeAndDequantizeV4Grad at 0x7849b91d6c00>) in gradient.
Level 1:tensorflow:Registering QuantizeAndDequantizeV4Grad (<function _QuantizeAndDequantizeV4GradGrad at 0x7849b91d6ca0>) in gradient.
[Level 1           ] Registering QuantizeAndDequantizeV4Grad (<function _QuantizeAndDequantizeV4GradGrad at 0x7849b91d6ca0>) in gradient.

....
Some other stuff here
....


[Level 1           ] Registering BatchMatMul,flops (<function _calc_batch_mat_mul_flops at 0x78497f71f740>) in statistical functions.
Level 1:tensorflow:Enabling eager execution
[Level 1           ] Enabling eager execution
Level 1:tensorflow:Enabling v2 tensorshape
[Level 1           ] Enabling v2 tensorshape
Level 1:tensorflow:Enabling resource variables
[Level 1           ] Enabling resource variables
Level 1:tensorflow:Enabling tensor equality
[Level 1           ] Enabling tensor equality
Level 1:tensorflow:Enabling control flow v2
[Level 1           ] Enabling control flow v2
object address  : 0x78497bc234c0
object refcount : 2
object type     : 0x874120
object type name: RecursionError
object repr     : RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded')
lost sys.stderr

I cannot attach the entire code since it is very big, lots of line and I exceed the limit (like 130k lines) So i put just the first lines and the last ones.
I find a github issue:
https://github.com/autorope/donkeycar/issues/1171
Which is the same problem that I have. In the issue seems like the donkey version 5.1 fix the problem, but I have the 5.1 version and the problem still persist.
Any suggestion? Thanks
